# Looping the creation of multiple variables

Tags: javascript

I want to loop the creation of various variables as to cut down on lines of code. If I need to create 10 variables like so:

```
var par01 = document.createElement("p");
var par02 = document.createElement("p");
var par03 = document.createElement("p");
var par04 = document.createElement("p");
var par05 = document.createElement("p");
var par06 = document.createElement("p");
var par07 = document.createElement("p");
var par08 = document.createElement("p");
var par09 = document.createElement("p");
var par10 = document.createElement("p");
```

...using a basic For Loop. I seem to be having some issues in setting it up:

```
for (var loopCounter = 1; loopCounter < 11; loopCounter++) {
    var par[loopCounter] = document.createElement("p"); }
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to use a simple array.

Comment: Define an empty array outside your loop, then add a new element in it with each iteration

Comment: What's the error? In this case you're creating an array named 'par' that has the newly created elements.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: `var par[loopCounter]` is not valid, hence why it does not work.

Comment: The code is wrong and as @Vasan said in a comment below, loopCounter must start at 0.

Comment: Just for fun: `var par = Array.from({ length: 10 }, _ => document.createElement("p"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, just declare your array before the loop. You can either assign to each array item using the counter like you did, or probably easier to just use `push()`:

```js
var par = [];

for (var loopCounter = 1; loopCounter < 11; loopCounter++) {
  par.push(document.createElement("p"));
}

console.log(par.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array before the loop, then fill it with new entries inside the loop. You want dynamic declaration otherwise, that is a classical problem afaik.

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    arr.push( document.createElement("p") );
}
```

Comment: This will create 11 elements, OP needs only 10

Comment: You're right there. I used 11 since I saw this was the number used by OP, but they also set the looping variable to an initial value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

You better use an array instead of doing this kind of stuff.

```
var pCollection =Array();
for (var loopCounter = 1; loopCounter < 11; loopCounter++) {
    pCollection.push(document.createElement("p")); 
}
```

Now to access your elements just iterate over the array;

```
for (var loopCounter = 1; loopCounter < pCollection.length; loopCounter++) {
    var pElement = pCollection[loopCounter] ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define the array before, better (in performance terms) if you know the length previously.

```
var loopCounter, 
    par[] = new Array(11);
for (loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < array.length; loopCounter++) {
    par[loopCounter] = document.createElement("p"); 
}
```

If the length is dynamic, you can initialize empty, and add elements using push() function.

Comment: You need to use loopCounter-1 as index or start loopCounter from 0

Comment: Sorry @Vasan careless copy&paste. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `array` and `push` each `object` into it:

```js
var pCollection = [];
for (var loopCounter = 0; loopCounter < 10; loopCounter++) {
    pCollection.push(document.createElement("p")); 
}

console.log(pCollection);
```